# nginx try_files with add_header

Tags: nginx, single-page-application, nginx-location

Can someone explain this?

I have an nginx server block with this snippet in it:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Basically, I'm using this to serve an Angular SPA. It works well and great.

Now I wanted to append `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response. So I changed the block like so:

```
location / {
  if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
          add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
          return 204;
  }
  if ($request_method = 'GET') {
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  }
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Now whenever I access `http://<application>.com` I get the page and I'm able to navigate to subroutes like `http://<application>.com/some-page`. But if I directly try to access `http://<application>.com/some-page`, I'm getting an nginx 404. It wasn't the case before. If I comment out the `if` statement for `GET`, things go back to normal.

Why? What difference does the `if` statement make here?

Comment: You should [read this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

Comment: @RichardSmith Wow. Thanks. That was useful indeed. I kind of solved my situation by moving the `try_files` inside the `if` with GET block. Any idea if there's a more elegant way to do it?